# Duplicating data vs storing all in one big collection? Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I'm designing an app that will display a screen full of images, the images to be loaded are dependent on what category the user has selected.

Category A
10000 image URLs

Category B
10000 image URLs

or

Category X
2000 image URLs

Is it better practice to store all image URLs in one collection or to have a collection for each category?

I assume it's better to have a collection for each category, to save looking through all of Category A's image URLs when we just want to load images from Category B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is better until you know exactly how you want to query the data and protect it with security rules.  The first rule of data modeling in nosql databases like Firestore is to model the data in such a way that suits your intended queries.

The size of a collection doesn't matter at all.  Firestore queries scale with the number of documents you request, not the total size of the result set.  If you query for 10 documents in a collection of size 100,000, that costs the same as a query for 10 documents in a collection of size 1,000,000.  So don't let the size of the collection determine how you model your data.